# Pig script minimum execution time

Tags: apache-pig, execution-time, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm currently learning Pig and I'm executing my scripts inside Hortonworks Sandbox. What is bugging me from the very beginning is that the minimum execution time for a Pig script seems to be at least 30-40 seconds. Is that because I'm using the Hortonworks Sandbox or is a normal for Pig scripts? Is there a way to reduce the execution time, because this is really slowing my learning progress? If this execution time is normal can you explain me what is going on and why is that?

PS

I've allocated 2GB RAM for the Hortonworks virtual machine. And just to mention I'm currently executing just simple scripts on small data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute pig in local mode (pig -x local) then it'll run a lot faster but it won't do map-reduce and won't access hdfs - it's good for learning though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 30-40 seconds is absolutely normal for Pig, because it has a big overhead for compiling the job, launching JVMs, etc.
As stated in the other answer - you can try to run in local mode. It usually takes me about 15 seconds for a simple job with input containing just a few lines of data. My Cloudera VM is allocated with 4G of RAM, btw.